# Optimizing number of production runs?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, economics

I am having trouble with the following problem:

A manufacturer of hospital supplies has a uniform annual demand for $180, 000$ boxes of bandages. It costs $20$ dollars to store one box of bandages for one year and $320$ dollars to set up production. How many times a year should the manager decide to produce boxes of bandages in order to minimize the total cost of storage and setup?

I think this problem is a little bit unclear. If it costs $20$ dollars to store one box for a year, I'm not sure that this implies a one time flat fee of $20$ dollars, or if it means that storing it for half a year will only cost $10$ . I can see the tradeoff between making too many or too few bandages in one run, but I can't quite put it into equations.

Comment: Do the bandagest cost nothing to produce?

Comment: @5xu't  The problem doesn mention anything about production cost

Comment: Ah, yes, it does not matter, since you have to produce 180,000 of them anyway. Well, I think that the 20 dollars per year means that it's 10 dollars for half a year, yes. Otherwise I don't see the point of the exercise.

Comment: @5xum So I can think of the problem intuitively, but could you help me get down the actual formulas? I know I am supposed to end up with a function  of the cost and find critical points to find the relative min

Comment: Say $x$ "times" a year, where $x$ need not be an integer. So each time we produce $K/x$, where $K=180000$. Now storage cost is tricky, I would lean to $20\cdot \frac{K}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{2x}\cdot x$ since on average a box is stored for $1/2$ of $1/x$ of a year. That gives cost function $320x+\frac{10K}{x}$.

Comment: @Ovi Did the answer help? I´m waiting for a reply for more than 4 years. **;)**

Comment: @callculus Haha thanks for waiting :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exercise can be managed by using the [EOQ-formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_order_quantity#The_Total_Cost_function_and_derivation_of_EOQ_formula).

In your case the total costs are

$TC=\frac{K \cdot D}{Q}+\frac{Q\cdot h}{2}=\frac{320 \cdot 180,000}{Q}+\frac{Q\cdot 20}{2}$

$P$ = store costs per year

$Q$ = produce quantity

$D$ = annual demand quantity

$K$ = Set up production cost

$h$=storage cost per unit

The derivative w.r.t Q is

$\frac{\partial TC}{\partial Q}=-\frac{K \cdot D}{Q^2}+\frac{ h}{2}=0$

*Solving for Q*

$\frac{K \cdot D\cdot 2}{h}=Q^2$

$Q^*=\sqrt{\frac{K \cdot D\cdot 2}{h}}$

After you have calculated the optimal produce quantity the number of cost minimizing set ups is $\frac{D}{Q^*}$